# Bug when viewing a list of questions based on tag

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, ignored-tags, search

I recently viewed the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-spirit

I noticed that despite there being 387 questions tagged and 50 questions per page, I only saw 1 question on this page.

When I viewed on a browser where I wasn't logged in I noticed all the questions appeared, however when I logged in, the questions were once again gone.

I tried this with `c#`, `ruby-on-rails`, etc... and it displayed properly, but this occurs with other ones as well (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/template-meta-programming, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-spirit-qi)

[image: Only 1 question visible]

Comment: Not seein' it.  Try refreshing your cache.

Comment: Not seeing it either.  SO must have been oscillating.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is probably because you have a tag that is commonly paired with that one in your block list and the site is filtering out all the ones that you don't want to see. Try hitting up the home page and checking your "ignored tags" and see if there is anything in there that might be commonly paired with [boost-spirit](/questions/tagged/boost-spirit).

If that doesn't hold any clues, do try again in about half an hour and do a hard refresh on the search page. Sometimes caching gets a little wacky.

Comment: you're right, I'm filtering out the c++ tag. Removing that from my ignored list resolves this issue